# How to prevent css inheritance?

Tags: html, css

how do i prevent css from inheriting in any of the child div (with text B in my example)

```css
.parent > div {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
   <div class="parent">
        <div>A
            <div>B</div>
        </div>
        <div>A
            <div>B</div>
        </div>
        <div>A
            <div>B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You cannot *prevent* inheritance, and color belongs to the inherited properties. You can only *overwrite* the inherited color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You selector is correct and its rule-set applies only to the immediate divs of the *.parent* element. The problem is with the *color* property, because color is an inherited property. So all elements inside *.parent > div* will have *color: red*, even if they are spans, sections etc.

An easy approach to deal with that is to set all divs with some color, and then add your selector. But as you can see in the example below all the elements inside our target div have their color as red, apart from the ones that we have set them elsewhere.

```css
div {
  color: black;
}

.parent > div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div> DIV A
    <div> DIV B </div>
    <span> SPAN </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course you can add another rule set with the universal selector (*) to reset the color property like this:

```css
.parent > div {
  color: red;
}

.parent > div > * {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div> DIV A
    <div> DIV B </div>
    <span> SPAN </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

A better approach is when you use properties like color, to use them only to the actual element that you want to target (unless if you want all childs to use that property), and if there is not, add one like that:

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div> 
    <span class="red">SPAN with red text</div>
    <div>DIV B </div>
    <span>SPAN</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can do this.

```css
.parent div {
  color: initial;
}

.parent>div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>A
    <div>B</div>
  </div>
  <div>A
    <div>B</div>
  </div>
  <div>A
    <div>B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant prevent inhertance, an alternative to dogukan's solution is to give the div with text Bs a class and style them to the default styles like this

```css
.parent > div{
    color:red;
}
.textB{
    color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
        <div>A
            <div class="textB">B</div>
        </div>
        <div>A
            <div class="textB">B</div>
        </div>
        <div>A
            <div class="textB">B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add class to the divs.

```css
.parent > div > div{
    color: blue;
}

.parent > .child{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
   <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">A
            <div>B</div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">A
            <div>B</div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">A
            <div>B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But you can also use the

```
color: inherit
```

What it does is specify that a property should inherit its value from its parent element.

```css
.parent div {
  color: initial;
}

.parent>div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>A
    <div>B</div>
  </div>
  <div>A
    <div>B</div>
  </div>
  <div>A
    <div>B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```